# How to add a vertical line to GWT AnnotatedTimeLine or LineChart?

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I want to add a vertical line to my AnnotatedTimeLine or LineChart to indicate an event that happens at that time. How can I do that in GWT?

Thanks,

Sean Nguyen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is supported in the GWT implementation or not, but in the core javascript implementation, you can use an "annotation" role column in a LineChart to add a vertical line.  Add a "string" type column to your DataTable, immediately after the domain (x-axis) column, give this column the "annotation" role, and input a label for the annotation at whatever x-axis point you need to insert a vertical line (this column should be null for other rows).  In the chart's options, specify the style of this annotation as "line".

```
function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    data.addRows([
        ['Foo', null, 4],
        ['Bar', null, 3],
        ['Baz', null, 7],
        ['Bat', null, 9],
        ['Cad', 'Vertical line here', 9],
        ['Qud', null, 2],
        ['Piz', null, 6]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 300,
        width: 400,
        annotation: {
            // index here is the index of the DataTable column providing the annotation
            1: {
                style: 'line'
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint. I don't know how to add the annotation to gwt either. I am new to gwt. Do you know how to make rpc call to gwt? If I can do that i can apply your code in my java script file

Comment: I don't use GWT, so I can't help you much there; I would suggest trying to set a "role" property on the column.  The annotation option should work exactly the same as the other chart options in GWT.

Comment: thanks for your pointer, i was able to do that in the following response

Comment: Why does the column with the `annotation` role always has to be the second column? The line doesn't show when the column is placed in the end. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used the Visualization API, so I don't recall the reason. Try setting the index of the annotation to the index of the column containing the annotations. Eg: if the annotations are in the 4th column, use `annotation: {3: {style: 'line'}}`.

Comment: That didn't work.. I ask because I am trying to implement toggling of series, and it doesn't work correctly when an annotation column is second, but it works when it is at the end. I am using [your implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/) of it.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of what you have so far? I'll take a look and see if I can figure out how to make it work. I suspect that you need to add the axis annotation to the base `columns` array: `var columns = [0, 1];`. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/880/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that in GWT based on the hint from asgallant. Here is the code

```
private native void addAnnotationColumn(DataTable data) /*-{
        data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 drawAnnotationTableInGWT(){    


private AnnotationChart annotatedChart; 



dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE,"DateTime");    
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER , "fuel capacity");    
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING,"Fuel info");    
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Speed (in kmph)");    
        dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING,"Speed info");        
        //dataTable.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING);    

dataTable.addRows(5);    

dataTable.setValue(0, 0,new Date("10/07/1993")); 




dataTable.setValue(0, 0,22);    
dataTable.setValue(1, 0,"khkjh");    
dataTable.setValue(1, 0,"sggixg");    
dataTable.setValue(0, 0,new Date("10/07/1993"));    
dataTable.getColumnRange(1);    

annotatedChart= new AnnotationChart();    
        annotatedChart.draw(dataTable,options());    
HoriZontalPanel chartPanel.add(annotatedChart);    
        String height=vpMain.getOffsetHeight()-110+"px";    
        annotatedChart.setSize("99%", height);    
        annotatedChart.getElement().getStyle().setPaddingRight(0, Unit.PX);    
        annotatedChart.getElement().getStyle().setPaddingLeft(0, Unit.PX);    
}        
private AnnotationChartOptions options(){    
        AnnotationChartOptions options=AnnotationChartOptions.create();    
        options.setDisplayAnnotations(true);    
        options.setDisplayZoomButtons(false);    
        options.setDisplayLegendDots(true);    
        options.setAnnotationsWidth(20);    
        options.setZoomStartTime(startDate);    
        options.setZoomEndTime(endDate);
        options.setDisplayExactValues(true);
        options.setAllowHtml(true);
        options.setThickness(2);
        options.setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a");
        options.setScaleType(ScaleType.ALLFIXED);
        options.setLegendPosition(ColoredLegendPosition.NEWROW);
        options.setColors("#66b032","#DC3912","#4684EE");
       // options.setAnnotationsWidth(200);
        return options;
    }
```